# Duplicate dialogue box showing suggestions for a different question

Tags: bug, review-queues, duplicate-questions

I was going to mark [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4842690) review as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937313/3204827) question. When I go into the close options to mark it as a duplicate, a few suggested questions are listed. I noticed that those questions have **nothing** to do with the question asked because it thinks I am trying to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4840416) question (a review audit).

[image]

When I go to the actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23721945/3204827) and flag it as a duplicate, a better selection of suggestions appear.

[image]

I think there might be a caching issue with the reviews, that is causing this.

This might be possible more suited for MSE (since it might happen on other sites as well), but since it happened to me SO, I'm posting it here.

EDIT:
I voted to close the question as a duplicate, but when I checked it, it wasn't recorded as a vote (but the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4842690) does say that I voted to close it). I had to go to the actual question and report it as a duplicate from there and it was actually counted as a vote there.

ANOTHER EDIT: I just noticed that this is a bug caused by [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255392/3204827) bug.

Comment: I also just came across this bug. I noticed that the incorrect suggestions were for a question that had appeared earlier in my queue.