# Close votes review audits kinda broken?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, review-audits

I was doing some reviews in close votes queue and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4848024) review audit. The first problem with that audit is that I couldn't see the reason it was flagged.

[image]

But I looked at the question and went to close the question because it doesn't provide enough information and was a poor question, but when I clicked on the `Close` option I got the message ``

After refreshing the page I can see the reason it was flagged.

[image]

Pressing the `Close` option, brings up the correct dialogue box. When the text `This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status.` appeared, I open the actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23693790/3204827) to look at it. It was closed a few days ago so I shouldn't have see the `This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status.` text. This happened to me yesterday as well, so it's not a one time bug.

I just noticed that if I flag the next question after that review audit I come across another bug that I reported [yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255346/3204827).

So it looks like the two bugs are related?